# useState undefined BUT value is defined

Tags: reactjs

```
        let data = new FormData()
        data.set('key', '')
        data.append('image', userPFP.file)
    
        const res = await fetch('https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
        })

        const parseRes = await res.json()

        if (!parseRes.status === 200) {
          return toast.error("Something went wrong")
        }

        const i = setImage(parseRes.data.display_url)
        console.log(i)
```

parseRes.data.display_url is existing and i can log it but when i put it in state it is sometimes defined and sometimes undefined

Comment: What does `setImage` means ? is it the function to set the state inside the component ? Please provide the code for the complete component. And where do you invoke above code snippet ? Is it executed inside a use effect or during an event ?

Comment: asuming your state is declared like this: `const [image, setImage] = useState(...)` you are not supposed to assign setImage to a variable, setImage modifies the value of "image", what you should console.log is "image", and btw fetching logic should be inside useEffect hook